# best complexity to solve apecial equation

Tags: time-complexity

For arbitrary integer number n>100 we can write n=3*a+5*b+7*c where a,b and c are non-negative numbers.

What is the best complexity for find a,b and c?

> If a,b and c be integer this problem is so easy and time complexity is `O(1)` because `n=3*2*n-5*n` so `a=2*n,b=-n and c=0`

Comment: Bruteforce would be something along `O(n^2)`. But I think, one maybe could get better results using dynamic programming.

Comment: this gives you one solution, but not all. I was thinking of listing all solutions. Anyways, if you have an `O(1)` algorithm, what more do you want?

Comment: @Sirko, In this solution b was negative. I'm looking for non negative a,b and c. Listing all solutions is not need. One solution is enough.

Comment: in that case my initial comment holds. one could think about dynamic programming solutions to reduce from `O(n^2)`